# SO Link-only Parser: Parse Stack Overflow for potentially link-only answers

Tags: app, answers, python

The provided Python script is designed to identify potentially "link-only" answers on Stack Overflow for a specified time period and set of tags. It does this by leveraging the Stack Exchange API to fetch questions and their associated answers, applying certain criteria to determine if an answer is primarily composed of links. Here's a breakdown of its functionality:

1. **Configuration and Constants**: The script starts by importing necessary libraries and setting up constants such as the number of days in a month, body length limit for an answer to be considered link-only, page size for API requests, and log level. It also specifies tags to filter the questions by and the date range for the search.
2. **Logging Setup**: It configures logging to record the process, including found link-only answers, to a log file named according to the specified start and end dates.
3. **Date Range Processing**: A generator function `month_range` is defined to iterate over each month within the specified date range, facilitating the handling of the Stack Exchange API's time window limitations.
4. **Configuration File Loading**: The script loads an external configuration file that contains the API key needed to authenticate requests to the Stack Exchange API.
5. **API Requests**: Using a loop, the script sends requests to the Stack Exchange API to retrieve questions within the specified date range, filtered by the provided tags. For each month in the range, it processes questions page by page until all questions have been fetched.
6. **Link-only Answer Identification**: For each question, it checks if there are answers and then filters these answers based on criteria for being considered potentially link-only. This includes the presence of "http" in the body (excluding links from `https://i.stack.imgur.com`), absence of `<code>` tags, and a body length below a certain limit. Each identified link-only answer's URL is constructed and logged, and the link is added to a list for further processing.
7. **Error Handling and Rate Limiting**: The script includes error handling for request failures and respects the API's rate limiting by sleeping for the amount of time specified in the `backoff` field of the API response, if present.
8. **Output**: Finally, the script prints the number of identified link-only answers. Although there's commented-out code that suggests an intention to open these links in a web browser, this functionality is not enabled in the provided version of the script.

This tool aims to assist in moderating content by identifying answers that might not meet the community's standards for quality and completeness, specifically targeting answers that may rely too heavily on links without providing sufficient context or explanation.

[Stack Overflow Tools on GitHub](https://github.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/tree/master/Tools)

```python
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import configparser
import time
import webbrowser
import logging
from pathlib import Path


# Load the constants configuration file
constants = configparser.ConfigParser()

# Define the relative path to the config file
constants_file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "so_linkonly_parser_config.ini"

# Read the config file
constants.read(constants_file_path)

# Access the constants
DAYS_IN_MONTH = constants.getint('DEFAULT', 'DAYS_IN_MONTH')
BODY_LENGTH_LIMIT = constants.getint('DEFAULT', 'BODY_LENGTH_LIMIT')
PAGE_SIZE = constants.getint('DEFAULT', 'PAGE_SIZE')
LOG_LEVEL = constants.get('DEFAULT', 'LOG_LEVEL')
tags = constants.get('DEFAULT', 'TAGS')
start_date = constants.get('DEFAULT', 'START_DATE')
end_date = constants.get('DEFAULT', 'END_DATE')

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename=f"./logs/{start_date}_{end_date}_link_only.log", level=LOG_LEVEL
)


def month_range(start_date, end_date):
    """Generate start and end dates for each day in the range."""
    while start_date < end_date:
        yield start_date, start_date + timedelta(days=1)
        start_date += timedelta(days=2)


# Get the current script's directory
current_dir = Path(__file__).parent

# Define the relative path to the config file
config_file_path = current_dir / ".." / ".." / "config_api.ini"

# Load the configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

# Read the config file
config.read(config_file_path)

# Get the API key from the configuration file
api_key = config.get("stackapps", "key")

# Define the API endpoint for questions
questions_url = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions"

# Define the start and end dates
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

# Create a list to store the links
links = []

for start_date_month, end_date_month in month_range(start_date, end_date):
    # Convert the dates to Unix timestamp
    start_date_unix = int(start_date_month.timestamp())
    end_date_unix = int(end_date_month.timestamp())

    # Log start_date_str
    logging.info(
        f"Start Date: {start_date_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}, End Date: {end_date_month.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
    )

    page = 1
    while True:
        # Define the parameters for the API request
        params = {
            "order": "desc",
            "sort": "creation",
            "tagged": tags,  # Search for posts with these tags
            "fromdate": start_date_unix,
            "todate": end_date_unix,
            "site": "stackoverflow",
            "filter": "!-*jbN-o8P3E5",
            "key": api_key,
            "page": page,
            "pagesize": PAGE_SIZE,
        }

        try:
            # Send the API request
            response = requests.get(questions_url, params=params)
            data = json.loads(response.text)

            # If no items are returned, we've reached the end of the results
            if not data["items"]:
                break

            # For each question, parse the 'answers' key directly
            for question in data["items"]:
                # Check if the question has answers
                if "answers" in question:
                    # Filter for answers that may primarily be link-only and exclude links from https://i.stack.imgur.com
                    link_only_answers = [
                        item
                        for item in question["answers"]
                        if "http" in item["body"]
                        and "https://i.stack.imgur.com" not in item["body"]
                        and "<code>" not in item["body"]
                        and len(item["body"]) < BODY_LENGTH_LIMIT
                    ]

                    if link_only_answers:
                        logging.info(f"Question ID: {question['question_id']}")
                        # Log the link-only answers
                        for answer in link_only_answers:
                            link = f"https://stackoverflow.com/a/{answer['answer_id']}"
                            logging.info(
                                f"Answer ID: {answer['answer_id']}, Link: {link}"
                            )
                            # Add the link to the list
                            links.append(link)
            logging.info(f'Remaining Quota: {data["quota_remaining"]}')
            if "backoff" in data:
                time.sleep(data["backoff"])

            # Increment the page number for the next request
            page += 1

        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            logging.error(f"Request failed: {e}")
            time.sleep(5)

# print the number of links
print(f"Number of link-only answers: {len(links)}")

# Open the links in a browser
# for link in links:
#     webbrowser.open(link)
```

---

**so_linkonly_parser_config.ini**

- `TAGS` can be multiple tags separated by a `;`, such as `python;matplotlib`.

```
[DEFAULT]
DAYS_IN_MONTH = 32
BODY_LENGTH_LIMIT = 500
PAGE_SIZE = 100
LOG_LEVEL = INFO
TAGS = python
START_DATE = 2024-01-01
END_DATE = 2024-01-31
```

**config_api.ini**

```
[stackapps]
client_id = ...
client_secret = ...
key = ...
redirect_uri = https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/login_success
```